# setting a default matlab path at startup

Tags: matlab

My team is trying to standardise our Matlab paths so that everyone has the same.

I have a list of the default matlab path that we should all have.

So we would like to have a script that runs when matlab opens to make sure that our paths are set to the default matlab path. So if a path has been added to our default list it will be added in the correct place.

Is this possible in Matlab?

I read about startup but that seems to do with set your working directory which is different to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change which directory MATLAB starts in using the [`userpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html) function so that whenever you start up MATLAB, the path will automatically redirect here.

This may be useful if you have MATLAB running on a network per se, and multiple instances can start in the same network directory.

See more from MathWorks here:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/matlab-startup-folder.html

---

However, if you want to standardize everything so that everyone has access to the same path, you can use `startup` to add directories / folders to MATLAB's path, but if you want to complete the package, use `userpath` to get MATLAB to start at a specified directory.

Your `startup.m` file may look something like this:

```
addpath('/folder/to/add/one');
addpath('/folder/to/add/two');
addpath('/folder/to/add/three');
addpath('/folder/to/add/four');
```

Then set your `userpath` with the function to complete everything:

```
userpath('/folder/to/start');
addpath('/folder/to/start');
```

Also make sure you add this new folder to your `startup.m` file too.

Answer (score 2):

Include a [`path`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) or [`addpath`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) line in file [`startup.m`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html). For example, to add folder `aaa\bbb` to the path the line would be

```
addpath('aaa\bbb')
```

Note that each user may have a different `startup.m` file. You may need to create it, if it doesn't already exist.